# Finite field extension

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Let $K\supset F$ be a finite field extension of degree 2 and the characteristic of $F$ is not 2. Show that there exists an isomorphism of rings $\sigma:K\to K$ such that

$$F=\{x\in K:\sigma(x)=x\}.$$

In this case, I didn't see why we need the condition char $F\neq 2$. The extension has degree 2 this means this extension is algebraic. Then I am thinking of using the polynomial ring over $F$. Then I get stuck. Any hints?

Comment: Have you any idea about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Is there a $w\in K\setminus F$ such that $w^2 \in F$? (here you will need the hypothesis ${\text {char}}(F)\neq 2$ and $[K:F]=2$). Now, the last hint is: think about the automorphisms of ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{2})$, relate it to your problem.

Comment: Now I have some idea. Since the extension has degree 2,then there is $x\in K-F$ s.t. $K=F(x)$. Then the minimal polynomial $p(T)$ of $x$ has degree 2,hence $p(T)=(T-x)q(T)$ which forces $q(T)$ to have degree 1. so $p(T)=(T-x)(T-y)$ for some $y\in K-F$. Then I am considerring the morphism $\sigma:K\to K, \sigma(a+bx)=a+by$ where $a,b\in F$. I hope now I am on the right track. Intuitively I notice that something bad can happen if char $F=2$, but I have some trouble constructing a counter example. Any counter examples for char $F=2$?

Comment: Well, if it had characteristic 2, then you have the property $(a+b)^2 = a^2+b^2$, and so actually $x$ can equal $y$ in your $p(T)$ (note $(T-x)^2 = T^2 - x^2$ and if $x^2 \in F$ then this is "ok"). 
You are on the right track, that $\sigma$ you defined should be a morphism.

Comment: Consider $F = {\mathbb F}_2(x^2)$ and $K = {\mathbb F}_2(x)$ (here $x$ is a symbol, also check $[K:F]$). Then consider $w \in K \setminus F$, note that necessarily $w^2 \in F$ (here you need ${\text char}(F) = 2$) and so the irreducible for $w$ over $F$ is $p(X)=(X-w)^2 = X^2 - w^2$. 
Here the two roots are the same, and so $F \neq K = \{v \in K : \sigma(v) = v\}$ if you defined $\sigma$ like that.